# Cleaning up KDE application menu (applications-kmenuedit.menu)

Tags: kde, desktop, menu-editor

Whenever I use the KDE menu editor to change the layout of the KDE application menu, the configuration file `~/.config/menus/applications-kmenuedit.menu` changes.

This file seems to collect a lot of garbage every time an item is created, moved, changed, or deleted. It has now grown to over 100kB and is very confusing to read, and I am having trouble with menus that refuse to be renamed. There are still entries for applications I removed years ago.

Is there any way I can clean this file from unnecessary junk that's accumulated?
I don't want to delete it and start from scratch because it would be a lot of work to recreate my highly customized menus

Answer (score 11):

I think the menu file is generated from the `*.desktop` files on your system.

You may look at the following locations

- /usr/share/applications
- ~/.local/share/applications/

And remove whatever you don't need. (Or add `Hidden=true` the desktop file)

Comment: If I were to delete the menu file and restart from scratch then it would be recreated from the .desktop files. But starting from scratch is exactly what I am trying to avoid, because I want my personal menu structure

Comment: If the menu file is deleted, then /etc/xdg/menus/applications.menu is used as the default

Comment: note to self for OpenSuse:   
/home/martin/.local/share/applications/OmegaT.desktop    
/home/martin/.config/menus/applications-kmenuedit.menu

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal and give the command: `kmenuedit`.
That's all, you can edit your menu via a GUI.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. Editing the menu with `kmenuedit` just leaves even more cruft in the menu file. Deleting an entry leaves the entry in the file, but marked as 'deleted'. Moving an entry leaves the original entry with a link to the new one.